# Callback for creation of nested model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

Is it possible in the `Category` model to understand if there's a `Post` instance being created along with the saving of a `Category` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `posts` collection from the `category` instance to see if any new records exist. If so they'll be saved when `category` is.

```
category.posts.any?(&:new_record?)
```